# cannot find richtext box control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, richtextbox

I am using visual studio 2010. The problem is I am looking for rich text box control in the toolbox but i am unable to find it. isn't it available in vs 2010 or is it only me who couldn't find it out. please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RichTextBox control is only available in Windows Forms development, not ASP.NET development.

The most often referenced free ASP.NET solution is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: Glad this helped you, feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)