# Richtext box control in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I am trying to incorporate a feature like Richtextbox control in my .NET Web application. Couldn't find it in my toolbox. Need help

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot find richtext box control in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855418/cannot-find-richtext-box-control-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio does not provide this control for Web Forms! You should check this out http://ckeditor.com